# Matlab GUI Scrollbar Available

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know if I can make a horizontal and vertical scroll bar in a MATLAB GUI (not a list box)? Depending on the resolution of a computer it may or may not show all of the figure so I need to be able to scroll (horizontally in my case). How to do that?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5253-scrolling-figure-demo

Comment: thanks, but I can't see the page. May you please explain it here?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see the page"?

Comment: The page doesn't open in my browser. It keeps loading but never opens. Even I don't have access to matlab website. It's restricted in my country.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a figure with a horizontal scrollbar:

```
figure
plot(1:3);
b = uicontrol('Parent',gcf,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','Normalize',...
    'Position',[0,0,1,0.05],...
    'min',0, 'max',1,...
    'Value', 0);
```

However, if I were you, I would rather make sure the figure fits the screen and allow the user to zoom. Having a graph larger than screensize deprives the user from observing the entire graph at once.

You could
a) let matlab choose default figure size of the figure. Then the user can fullscreen if desired, or b)

```
screensize = get(groot,'Screensize');
figure('Position',screensize)
```

I hope this helps.